# Display a div based on a checkboxes' value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a div in a form (`#sides`) that I only want displayed when one checkbox (`.opp-choice-checkbox`) is not checked. Here's the code I have right now:

```
jQuery ->
  if !$(".opp-choice-checkbox").checked
    $("#sides").hide()
  $(".opp-choice-checkbox").click ->
    $("#sides").slideToggle()
```

A similar question is asked a lot, but the difference with my question is that when I go to edit the object the form is for, sometimes the checkbox is checked by default. In that situation, I want the div to be showing when the page is loaded. The code I have right now hides the div by default, regardless of whether or not the checkbox is checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Your code working perfectly with the little update mentioned below, See **[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SKMpV/509/)** for your code:

**CoffeeScript :**

You have just to add the `else` in your condition to show the div if the `checkbox` is checked :

```
jQuery ->
  if !$(".opp-choice-checkbox").is(":checked")
    $("#sides").hide()
  else
    $("#sides").show()

  $(".opp-choice-checkbox").click ->
    $("#sides").slideToggle()
```

If sometimes you have a chekcked `checkbox` by default, you have just to remove condition and replace your coofee code by the following :

```
jQuery ->
  $(".opp-choice-checkbox").change ->
    $("#sides").slideToggle()
```

See fiddle **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/SKMpV/512/)**.

I hope this will help.

Comment: That true, see my update `$(".opp-choice-checkbox").is(":checked")`, and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`$(".opp-choice-checkbox")` doesn't have a `checked` property - that's a jQuery element. To get the regular DOM elem, use `[0]`

```
$(".opp-choice-checkbox")[0].checked
```

Or, use `.is("checked")`

```
$(".opp-choice-checkbox").is("checked")
```

If this is all attached to a `change` or `click` event, just run that event on load to trigger the behavior, (`$(elem).change(function() { }).change()`)